# Ubuntu list of packages installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, packages

I am moving to a new laptop with Ubuntu Lucid from an old laptop that has Ubuntu Karmic.

I want to look at the list of all the packages and selectively install them all on the new laptop.

What is the best method to go about doing this?

Comment: What an excellent question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
  dpkg --get-selections > package.list
```

to write the list of packages to the file package.list and edit it if you want

On the new machine use

```
  sudo dpkg --set-selections < package.list
  sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

to install the packages

Comment: You can also use dpkg -l to show all installed packages with their descriptions so you can decide which ones you want. Just edit package.list as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

A better list is obtained from:

```
aptitude search '~i !~M'
```